# Completable creation NPEs only on Android 4

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

I am getting a lot of NPE crashes on Crashlytics that are related with an rx-wrapper I've created for FirebaseRemoteConfig.

My code:

```
public Completable fetch() {
    remoteConfig.activateFetched();

    return Completable.create(e ->
            remoteConfig.fetch(cacheExpiration).addOnCompleteListener(
                    task -> {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Config fetched successfully");
                            remoteConfig.activateFetched();
                            if (!e.isDisposed()) {
                                e.onComplete();
                            }
                        } else {
                            if (!e.isDisposed()) {
                                Log.e(TAG, "Config fetch error", task.getException());
                                e.onError(task.getException());
                            }
                        }
                    }));
}
```

And then I subscribe to it like this:

```
    composite.clear();

    composite.add(
            helper.fetch()
                    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                    .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                    .subscribeWith(new DisposableCompletableObserver() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete() {
                            Timber.tag(TAG).d("Remote config fetched");
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onError(@NonNull Throwable throwable) {
                            Timber.tag(TAG).d(throwable, "Remote config fetch error");
                        }
                    })
    );
```

I get 3 types of crashes:

```
Crash #1
        Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableCreate.subscribeActual(CompletableCreate.java:36)
           at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1635)
           at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn$SubscribeOnObserver.run(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:64)
           at io.reactivex.Scheduler$DisposeTask.run(Scheduler.java:452)
           at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.run(ScheduledRunnable.java:61)
           at io.reactivex.internal.schedulers.ScheduledRunnable.call(ScheduledRunnable.java:52)
           at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:152)
           at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:265)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


Crash #2
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:36)
       at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1635)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableObserveOn.subscribeActual(CompletableObserveOn.java:34)
       at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:

Crash #3
    Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableObserveOn$ObserveOnCompletableObserver.onSubscribe(CompletableObserveOn.java:68)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableSubscribeOn.subscribeActual(CompletableSubscribeOn.java:36)
       at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1635)
       at io.reactivex.internal.operators.completable.CompletableObserveOn.subscribeActual(CompletableObserveOn.java:34)
       at io.reactivex.Completable.subscribe(Completable.java:1635)
```

The curious thing is that the crashes only happen on Android 4, mainly 4.4 and 4.1.

Answer (score 2):

The thing all these errors have in common is that they appear to be caused by a `null` where a `CompletableObserver` is expected.

Given that the `subscribeWith` gets a valid object the only way for this to occur is through a misconfiguration of the `RxJavaPlugin.onSubscribe` hook, which can wrap observers and thus for some reason replace the observer with a `null`.

I suggest inspecting the `onCompletableSubscribe` field in the `RxJavaPlugins` class using reflection to see if there is some callback that might be acting weirdly on those java versions.